# Remove empty option from angularjs angular-formly select

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I recently upgraded my angularJs project from version 1.5.8 to 1.8.3. Since then I am seeing an empty option in the select drop down. How can I remove that option. I am using angular-formly for my form construction.